# NSRangeException while inserting rows with UIPickerView in between two static UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a static UItableView with four cells. when I try to insert a row after the third cell using insertRowsAtIndexPath tableView method and add UIPickerView to the added row I got this error: **uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'**

What I'm trying to achieve is the in-line datePicker in the iOS Calendar app but using a UIPickerView. I want to show a UIPicker / hide a pickerView immediately below the third row it is selected / deselected. I also want to do the same for last row.

**NOTE:** Adding the row with the pickerView works when I add below the fourth cell but doesn't work when inserting a cell between other cells.

If there is another way to achieve this without first creating the UIPickerView in the Storyboard, I would be glad.

```
var pickerIsVisible = false

func hidePicker() {
    pickerIsVisible = false
    let indexPathPicker = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathPicker], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func showPicker() {
    pickerIsVisible = true
    let indexPathPicker = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathPicker], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && (indexPath.row == 3 && pickerIsVisible) {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PickerCell") as UITableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "PickerCell")
            cell.selectionStyle = .None
            let picker = UIPickerView(frame: cell.frame)
            picker.tag = 100
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.dataSource = self
            cell.contentView.addSubview(picker)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 && pickerIsVisible {
        return 5
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        noteTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        pickerIsVisible ? hidePicker() : showPicker()
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && pickerIsVisible && indexPath.row == 3 {
        return 117
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, var indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 3 && pickerIsVisible {
        indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: indexPath.section)
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint to catch exactly where the problem occurs? If you're able to provide the complete source that could be run, it would be easier to investigate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by modifying these methods:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && pickerIsVisible && indexPath.row == 3 {
        return 117
    }
    if indePath.row == 4 && pickerIsVisisble {
        return 44
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, var indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    if indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 4 && pickerIsVisible {
        indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: indexPath.section)
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && (indexPath.row == 3 && pickerIsVisible) {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 200)
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: frame)
        picker.tag = 100
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        cell.contentView.addSubview(picker)
        return cell
    }
    if pickerIsVisible && indexPath.row == 4 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Time Cell") as UITableViewCell!
            return cell
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```